# What is a word to describe a person who mischievously and annoyingly refers to his/her friend as arrogant when that person is not?

Tags: word-choice

I encountered this person (guy) who mischievously and annoyingly refers to another person (girl) as arrogant when that person is not. I suspect that the guy is trying to tease the girl but in doing so, he made himself appear as childish and I am trying to find a word to describe this kind of character.

Comment: If you think he is childish, he is childish. If you think his behavior is annoying, he is annoying. If you think he is mean, he is mean. I think your question is too broad.

Comment: Infantile. Puerile. Juvenile. (He also might be in love with her!)

Comment: In Australia we'd call that person an arsehole [for non-native speakers and other geographies, this rhymes with "far soul" and means anus]. But it's not clear whether you're asking for a word that merely describes a person who is mischievous, annoying and childish, or you require that *in addition* the word captures being **slanderous**, or you *further* require that the word captures the specific case of a slanderous allegation of arrogance.

Answer (score 3):

**Wind-up merchant** — [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wind-up_merchant)

> *noun (England, colloquial)* One who enjoys winding others up in the sense of making fun of them or playing practical jokes

British colloquialism, but I would describe them as a wind up merchant (note it's wind as in wound, not wind as in north wind!)

Answer (score 1):

**Impish** ‎(comparative more impish, superlative most impish) [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/impish)

> (Adjective) impish ‎(comparative more impish, superlative most impish); mischievous; of or befitting an imp. Synonyms (naughtily or annoyingly playful): implike, mischievous, pixilated, prankish, puckish

*Puckish* is an interesting one. I didn't know that one before.

Answer (score 0):

> **Haughty** *adjective* (haughtier, haughtiest)
>
> Arrogantly superior and disdainful: a look of haughty disdain | a haughty British aristocrat.

Oxford Dictionary of English

Comment: I don't think "haughty" fits the question at all. The behaviour could equally be displayed by someone with a low self-opinion who is mean and nasty in a low-life kind of way, utterly not in a haughty way.

Answer (score 0):

**Teaser** — [Wiktionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/teaser)

> *noun* One who engages in teasing; a tease.

This might have other unfortunate meanings if you did not use it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

**Perverse** ‎(comparative perverser, superlative perversest) [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/perverse)

> (Adjective) Turned aside; hence, specifically, turned away from the (morally) right; willfully erring; wicked; perverted.

*Willfully perverse* might work better.